# which event fires if excel-vba modeless userform window gets focus back?

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a modeless userform in an Excel VBA project.
The userform is loaded by button on spreadsheet clicked (*not* an active-x button if that's relevant).
Because of modeless the user can work with excel or even other applications and than switch back to the form window. **I need an event that fires if the form window becomes the active window again.** I thought `UserForm_Activate` should do the job but it doesn't (neither does `UserForm_GotFocus` but there is no GotFocus event for userforms?). Is there any event that fires if the user switches back to a modeless userform (or in case not: is there any known work-around)? Or do I've got some strange bug here and `Activate` should fire?

Here's all the code I used for testing purpose:

```
' standard module:

Sub BUTTON_FormLoad()
    ' associated as macro triggered by button click on a sheet
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub


' UserForm1:

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ' does not fire if focus comes back
    Debug.Print "Activated"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_GotFocus()
    ' does not fire if focus comes back
    ' wrong code - no GotFocus event for userforms?
    Debug.Print "Focussed"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    ' only fires if clicked *inside* form
    ' does not fire eg if user clicks top of form window
    Debug.Print "Clicked"
End Sub
```

Where do I find the documentation of userform events? It's not on the '[UserForm object](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/userform-object)' page.

Comment: Here is a good page on user form events. https://bettersolutions.com/vba/userforms/events.htm

Comment: You can achieve what you want by subclassing the userform and trapping the worksheet events but it very messy.

Answer (score 2):

The `Activate` event doesn't fire when you switch between the application and a modeless userform. This is by design.

Like I mentioned in the comments

> You can achieve what you want by subclassing the userform and trapping the worksheet events but it very messy.

Here is a very basic example. Sample file can be downloaded from [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/20jjovfng5x1qgn/Modeless%20orm%20Activate%20Event.xlsm?dl=0)

**READ ME FIRST**:

1. This is just a basic sample. Please close all Excel Files before testing this.
2. If the user directly clicks a control on the userform and you want to run the `activate code` there as well then you will have to handle that as well.
3. Once you are happy, amend it to suit your need.

**Place code in a Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" _
(ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal msg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong& Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long)

Private Const GWL_WNDPROC = (-4)
Private WinProcOld As Long
Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = &HA1

Public formWasDeactivated As Boolean

'~~> Launch the form
Sub LaunchMyForm()
    Dim frm As New UserForm1
    frm.Show vbModeless
End Sub

'~~> Hooking the Title bar in case user clicks on the title bar
'~~> to activate the form
Public Function WinProc(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    If wMsg = WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN Then
        '~~> Ignoring unnecessary clicks to the title bar
        '~~> by checking if the form was deactivated
        If formWasDeactivated = True Then
            formWasDeactivated = False
            MsgBox "Form Activated"
        End If
    End If

    WinProc = CallWindowProc(WinProcOld&, hwnd&, wMsg&, wParam&, lParam&)
End Function

'~~> Subclass the form
Sub SubClassUserform(hwnd As Long)
    WinProcOld& = SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf WinProc)
End Sub

Sub UnSubClassUserform(hwnd As Long)
    SetWindowLong hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, WinProcOld&
    WinProcOld& = 0
End Sub
```

Create a Userform. Let's call it `Userform1`. Add a command button in the form. Let's call it `CommandButton1`

**Place code in Userform**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" _
Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Dim hwnd As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, Me.Caption)
    SubClassUserform hwnd
End Sub

'~~> Userform Click event
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    '~~> Ignoring unnecessary clicks
    '~~> by checking if the form was deactivated
    If formWasDeactivated = True Then
        formWasDeactivated = False
        MsgBox "Form Activated"
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Unload the form
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '~~> In case hwnd gets reset for whatever reason.
    hwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, Me.Caption)
    UnSubClassUserform hwnd

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Place this code in the **Workbook** code area

```
Option Explicit

'~~> Checking if the form was deactivated
'~~> Add more events if you want

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    formWasDeactivated = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    formWasDeactivated = True
End Sub
```

Please feel free to add more workbook events. I have only used `Workbook_SheetActivate` and `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`

And finally add a Form Button in the worksheet and assign the macro `LaunchMyForm` to it. And we are done

**In Action**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there isn't such an event within VBA. From the documentation:

> The Activate and Deactivate events occur only when you move the focus
> within an application. Moving the focus to or from an object in
> another application doesn't trigger either event.

However, the Windows APIs can handle the event with a *hook*. The problem with Win APIs within VBA is that errors aren't handled by VBA so Excel will crash if/when the code encounters an error; so they can be frustrating for the developer. From a purely personal perspective, I like to keep code within the hook procedures to a minimum and pass any values to a class that can then fire events - this at least minimises the crashes. It's also important to remember to unhook before finishing your session.

Basic implementation of a Win API hook would look something like this:

**In a class object (here it's called cHookHandler)**

```
Option Explicit

Public Event HookWindowActivated()
Public Event HookIdChanged()

Private mHookId As LongPtr
Private mTargetWindows As Collection

Public Property Get HookID() As LongPtr
    HookID = mHookId
End Property

Public Property Let HookID(RHS As LongPtr)
    mHookId = RHS
    RaiseEvent HookIdChanged
End Property

Public Sub AttachHook()
    modHook.AttachHook Me
End Sub

Public Sub DetachHook()
    modHook.DetachHook
End Sub

Public Sub AddTargetWindow(className As String, Optional windowTitle As String)
    Dim v(1) As String
    
    'Creates an array of [0 => className, 1=> windowTitle]
    'which is stored in a collection and tested for in
    'your hook callback.
    v(0) = className
    v(1) = windowTitle
    mTargetWindows.Add v
    
End Sub

Public Sub TestForTargetWindowActivated(className As String, windowTitle As String)
    Dim v As Variant
    
    'Tests if the callback window is one that we're after.
    For Each v In mTargetWindows
        If v(0) = className Then
            If v(1) = "" Or v(1) = windowTitle Then
                'Fires the event that our target window has been activated.
                RaiseEvent HookWindowActivated
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mTargetWindows = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    modHook.DetachHook
End Sub
```

**Module code (here the module is called modHook)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hHook As LongPtr) As Long
 
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
    (ByVal idHook As Long, _
    ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, _
    ByVal hmod As LongPtr, _
    ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hHook As LongPtr, _
    ByVal ncode As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
    lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetClassNameA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpString As String, _
    ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Const WH_CBT As Long = 5
Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE As Long = 5

Private mHookHandler As cHookHandler

Public Sub AttachHook(hookHandler As cHookHandler)
    Set mHookHandler = hookHandler
    mHookHandler.HookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, AddressOf CBTCallback, 0, GetCurrentThreadId)
End Sub

Private Function CBTCallback(ByVal lMsg As Long, _
                             ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
                             ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Dim className As String, windowTitle As String
    
    If mHookHandler Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    If lMsg = HCBT_ACTIVATE Then
        className = GetClassText(wParam)
        windowTitle = GetWindowTitle(wParam)
        If Not mHookHandler Is Nothing Then
            mHookHandler.TestForTargetWindowActivated className, windowTitle
        End If
    End If
    CBTCallback = CallNextHookEx(mHookHandler.HookID, lMsg, ByVal wParam, ByVal lParam)
End Function

Public Sub DetachHook()
    Dim ret As Long
    
    If mHookHandler Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ret = UnhookWindowsHookEx(mHookHandler.HookID)
    If ret = 1 Then
        mHookHandler.HookID = 0
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetWindowTitle(wParam As LongPtr) As String
    Dim tWnd As String
    Dim lWnd As Long
    
    tWnd = String(100, Chr(0))
    lWnd = GetWindowText(wParam, tWnd, 100)
    tWnd = Left(tWnd, lWnd)

    GetWindowTitle = tWnd
End Function

Private Function GetClassText(wParam As LongPtr) As String
    Dim tWnd As String
    Dim lWnd As Long
    
    tWnd = String(100, Chr(0))
    lWnd = GetClassName(wParam, tWnd, 100)
    tWnd = Left(tWnd, lWnd)

    GetClassText = tWnd
End Function
```

**And in this example, all events are captured within the `Userform`**

In this simple example, two buttons on the `Userform` attach and detach the hook, but you'd probably call the routines from somewhere else (perhaps the userform `Initialize` and `Terminate` events). The `Userform` also has a label `lblHook` displaying the HookId which I use during development - for production code, you probably wouldn't want this, so you could leave that bit out.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mHookHandler As cHookHandler

Private Sub btnHook_Click()
    mHookHandler.AttachHook
End Sub

Private Sub btnUnhook_Click()
    mHookHandler.DetachHook
End Sub

Private Sub mHookHandler_HookIdChanged()
    lblHook.Caption = mHookHandler.HookID
End Sub

Private Sub mHookHandler_HookWindowActivated()
    ' Caveat: this routine will crash if halted in debugger.
    Debug.Print "I've been activated!"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set mHookHandler = New cHookHandler
    
    mHookHandler.AddTargetWindow "ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Set mHookHandler = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout, sorry, missed your hooking answer while I was writing this. Think they're different enough to keep, but let me know and I'm happy to delete this answer.

Comment: Strange... I was testing your code on a modeless userform and it didn't work. will check in sometime again... [THIS](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wjho2t2lplkuo3/Delete%20Me%20Later.xlsm?dl=0) is the file with your code...

Comment: @SiddharhRout I've had that before, but works fine with `Userform1.Show False` instead of `vbModeless`. No idea why.

Comment: No it doesn't work with `False` as well. BTW `?vbModeless=False` will give you true. So it shouldn't matter :)

Comment: I have attached the sample file above. you can test it in that

Comment: @SiddharhRout  Odd. I've just tested the download and all working fine on my machine. Was your hook definitely attached?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200278/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-ambie).

Comment: I've build a [sample file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t1ETYpkuu2acNYfo3Z-5rqDO0M02tbXI) too; main results: (1) code works, (2) random crashes of Excel (O365 V1902 11328.20420), (3) if form hooked, "activate-event" fires *after* button click in case of form already had focus, (4) if form hooked, switching focus back to form by clicking form button does *not* fire the button-clicked-event (as it does if form is unhooked), (5) the fireing of the "activate-event" causes windows to play a sound (but only if focus switched over to form, see (3)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. the event occurs after the form appears, so hide the wb inside an initialize event.

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
Set WB = ThisWorkbook Windows(WB.Name).Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The event does not exist and you can use Windows hooks to achieve your desired result.  In my opinion, that's the direct answer and everything else is a workaround [unless it was posted by Siddharth Rout, in which case, THAT is the direct answer]

Comment: Unless there is another solution, IMO a workaround is a welcomed answer.